# python list comprehension to produce two values in one iteration

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I want to generate a list in python as follows -

```
[1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 9, 4, 16, 5, 25 .....]
```

You would have figured out, it is nothing but `n, n*n`

I tried writing such a list comprehension in python as follows -

```
lst_gen = [i, i*i for i in range(1, 10)]
```

But doing this, gives a syntax error.

What would be a good way to generate the above list via list comprehension?

Comment: The comment " Except I'll actually use a loop and `append`" is also the actual answer I come to after looking at these options. *Pick up a different screwdriver when the one you're using doesn't fit*

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable((i, i**2) for i in xrange(1, 6)))
[1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 9, 4, 16, 5, 25]
```

Or you can also use a [generator](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) function:

```
>>> def solve(n):
...     for i in xrange(1,n+1):
...         yield i
...         yield i**2

>>> list(solve(5))
[1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 9, 4, 16, 5, 25]
```

Answer (score 55):

The question is old, but just for the curious reader, i propose another possibility:
As stated on first post, you can easily make a couple (i, i**2) from a list of numbers. Then you want to flatten this couple. So just add the flatten operation in your comprehension.

```
[x for i in range(1, 10) for x in (i,i**2)]
```

Comment: This was the most promising solution I had in head before looking up the question and it know is my chosen solution for the problem. -- Except I'll actually use a loop and `append`.

Answer (score 18):

A little-known trick: list comprehensions can have multiple for clauses.

For example:

```
>>> [10*x+y for x in range(4) for y in range(3)]
[0, 1, 2, 10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22, 30, 31, 32]
```

In your particular case, you could do:

```
>>> [x*x if y else x for x in range(5) for y in range(2)]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 9, 4, 16]
```

Answer (score 8):

List comprehensions generate *one* element at a time. Your options are, instead, to change your loop to only generate one value at a time:

```
[(i//2)**2 if i % 2 else i//2 for i in range(2, 20)]
```

or to produce tuples then flatten the list using `itertools.chain.from_iterable()`:

```
from itertools import chain

list(chain.from_iterable((i, i*i) for i in range(1, 10)))
```

Output:

```
>>> [(i//2)**2 if i % 2 else i//2 for i in range(2, 20)]
[1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 9, 4, 16, 5, 25, 6, 36, 7, 49, 8, 64, 9, 81]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable((i, i*i) for i in range(1, 10)))
[1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 9, 4, 16, 5, 25, 6, 36, 7, 49, 8, 64, 9, 81]
```

Comment: I don't know if i should be fascinated or disgusted by the first solution

Answer (score 7):

You can create a list of lists then use reduce to join them.

```
print [[n,n*n] for n in range (10)]
```

[[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 4], [3, 9], [4, 16], [5, 25], [6, 36], [7, 49], [8, 64], [9, 81]]

```
print reduce(lambda x1,x2:x1+x2,[[n,n*n] for n in range (10)])
```

[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 9, 4, 16, 5, 25, 6, 36, 7, 49, 8, 64, 9, 81]

```
 print reduce(lambda x1,x2:x1+x2,[[n**e for e in range(1,4)]\
 for n in range (1,10)])
```

[1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 3, 9, 27, 4, 16, 64, 5, 25, 125, 6, 36, 216, 7, 49, 343, 8, 64, 512, 9, 81, 729]

Reduce takes a callable expression that takes two arguments and processes a sequence by starting with the first two items. The result of the last expression is then used as the first item in subsequent calls. In this case each list is added one after another to the first list in the list of lists and then that list is returned as a result.

List comprehensions implicitly call map with a lambda expression using the variable and sequence defined by the "**for** var **in** sequence" expression. The following is the same sort of thing.

```
map(lambda n:[n,n*n],range(1,10))
```

[[1, 1], [2, 4], [3, 9], [4, 16], [5, 25], [6, 36], [7, 49], [8, 64], [9, 81]]

I am unaware of a more natural python expression for reduce.

Answer (score 5):

```
lst_gen = sum([(i, i*i) for i in range(1, 10)],())
```

oh I should mention the sum probably breaks the one iteration rule :(

Comment: While this'll work, using `sum` this way gives quadratic performance and so is a somewhat dangerous habit to fall into.

Comment: yeah itertools woulda been better , but i kinda like the sum trick sometimes :P

Comment: @DSM, forgive my ignorance, why would using `sum()` with a list comprehension (of tuples) give quadratic performance? Part of my question is, what aspect of "this way" is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

A Simple one might be:

```py
[i ** j for i in range(1, 6) for j in [1, 2]]
```

Which is quite explicit regarding the task and the fact that the list comp replaces two nested loops (while as other answers show, can be flattened, so to speak).
Output:

```
[1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 9, 4, 16, 5, 25]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
reduce(lambda x,y: x + [y, y*y], range(1,10), [])
```

Comment: This requires importing in Python 3. (`functools`)

Comment: yes, from functools import reduce

Answer (score 2):

Another option, might seem perverse to some

```
>>> from itertools import izip, tee
>>> g = xrange(1, 11)
>>> x, y = tee(g)
>>> y = (i**2 for i in y)
>>> z = izip(x, y)
>>> output = []
>>> for k in z:
...     output.extend(k)
... 
>>> print output
[1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 9, 4, 16, 5, 25, 6, 36, 7, 49, 8, 64, 9, 81, 10, 100]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> lst_gen = [[i, i*i] for i in range(1, 10)]
>>> 
>>> lst_gen
[[1, 1], [2, 4], [3, 9], [4, 16], [5, 25], [6, 36], [7, 49], [8, 64], [9, 81]]
>>> 
>>> [num for elem in lst_gen for num in elem]
[1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 9, 4, 16, 5, 25, 6, 36, 7, 49, 8, 64, 9, 81]
```

Here is my reference
http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 2):

Lots of tricks in this thread. Here is another using a one liner generator without imports

```
x = (lamdba : [[(yield i), (yield i**2)] for i in range(10)])()
```

EDIT:
This will raise DeprecatedWarning in Python 3.7 and SyntaxError in Python 3.8:
https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.7.html#deprecated-python-behavior

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) is the way to go. Here's how I would do it, I find it more clear:

```
[i if turn else i*i for i,turn in itertools.product(range(1,10), [True, False])]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
anotherList = []
j = [0,1]
l = [(i,i*i) for i in range(1,10)]
print(l)
# O/P - [(1,1),(2,4),(3,9),(4,16),(5,25),....]
```

First, I have created a tuple consisting of the number with its square. Having another variable to store the index values is not necessary but helps to access the elements in the tuple at the later stage.

```
anotherList =[element[position] for element in l for position in j]
print(anotherList)
# O/P - [1,1,2,4,3,9,4,16,.....]
```

After all the tuples have been created in the list, we can now use another comprehension to first access the tuple and then use the index to access the elements within it. The comprehension does the rest to add all the elements in a 'clean' list.

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks for the comments. I added some color to the code. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

Try this two liner

```
lst = [[i, i*i] for i in range(10)]
[lst.extend(i) for i in lst]
```

Change math as necessary.

EVEN BETTER

```
#Change my_range to be the number you want range() function of
start = 1
my_range = 10
lst = [i/2 if i % 2 == 0 else ((i-1)/2)**2 for i in range(start *2, my_range*2 - 1)]
```