# split each item in list

Tags: python, list

Is it possible to split items in a list and generate a new list on the fly?
basically i get a list of ushort's and want to produce a list of ubytes:

```
input = [1036, 1055, 26, 29787, 9, 4206, 41, 7, 1036, 8302, 130, 4, 268, 4206]
out = [4, 12, 4, 31, 0, 26, 116, 91, 0, 9, 16, 110, 0, 41, 0, 7, 4, 12, 32, 110, 0, 130, 0, 4, 1, 12, 16, 110]
```

i can very easily generate a list of tuples, but how can i remove the tuples and merge them to one big list?

```
out_temp = [(x>>8, x&0xFF) for x in input]
```

Comment: Why don't you use a lambda funtion?

Answer (score 6):

You can use list comprehension this way:

```
>>> in_ = [1036, 1055, 26, 29787, 9, 4206, 41, 7, 1036, 8302, 130, 4, 268, 4206]
>>> [y for x in in_ for y in (x >> 8, x & 0xff)]
[4, 12, 4, 31, 0, 26, 116, 91, 0, 9, 16, 110, 0, 41, 0, 7, 4, 12, 32, 110, 0, 130, 0, 4, 1, 12, 16, 110]
```

or using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable((x >> 8, x & 0xff) for x in in_))
[4, 12, 4, 31, 0, 26, 116, 91, 0, 9, 16, 110, 0, 41, 0, 7, 4, 12, 32, 110, 0, 130, 0, 4, 1, 12, 16, 110]
```

BTW, don't use `input` as a variable name. It shadows builtin function [`input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to do with the converted data, you might also be interested in `array.array`.

```
>>> a = array.array("H", input)
>>> a.byteswap()
>>> a.tostring()
'\x04\x0c\x04\x1f\x00\x1at[\x00\t\x10n\x00)\x00\x07\x04\x0c n\x00\x82\x00\x04\x01\x0c\x10n'
>>> list(bytearray(a.tostring()))
[4, 12, 4, 31, 0, 26, 116, 91, 0, 9, 16, 110, 0, 41, 0, 7, 4, 12, 32, 110, 0, 130, 0, 4, 1, 12, 16, 110]
```

Comment: `byteswap` should be done conditionally. (depending on `sys.byteorder`)

Comment: falsetru: It really depends on what the OP wants to do.

Comment: I meant the code in the answer does not produce the same output in big endian systems.  You added `byteswap` to make the result to match with the `out` in the question. Didn't you?

Comment: @falsetru: Yes, of course I did, but he code ist mostly to demonstrate the concept.  Depending on the real-world use case, it might be necessary to byteswap conditionally (though big-endian systems have mostly -- and rightfully -- died by now).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16594904/python-list-comprehension-with-two-values-in-one-iteration) you can also use a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) function:

```
input_data = [1036, 1055, 26, 29787, 9, 4206, 41, 7, 1036, 8302, 130, 4, 268, 4206]

def convert(x):
    for i in x:
        yield i>>8
        yield i&0xFF

print list(convert(input_data))
```

Results

```
[4, 12, 4, 31, 0, 26, 116, 91, 0, 9, 16, 110, 0, 41, 0, 7, 4, 12, 32, 110, 0, 130, 0, 4, 1, 12, 16, 110]
```